# How to add custom thumbnail to a blogger homepage website when sharing main link?

Tags: java, html, css, blogger

In my blog when I share my post link on social media its automatically use the post thumbnail as a link img but when I share the homepage link it took the latest posts img as the thumbnail of the link how can I add coustom thumbnail to my main/homepage link without changing the post thumbnail feature [like YouTube or Facebook when we share Maine link it shows a default thumbnail but when we share a post or a video it automatically show's the post thumbnail or video thumbnail]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, maybe something like this works:

```
   <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
      <b:else/>
    <meta content='YOUR-IMAGE-URL' property='og:image'/>
    </b:if>
```

And for Twitter, maybe...

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' name='twitter:image'/>
  <b:else/>
<meta content='YOUR-IMAGE-URL' name='twitter:image'/>
</b:if>
```

I've been using this to show a default image when the post don't have any image, but I assume it can be adjusted to the non-post pages by using the `<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>` conditional.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
  <meta content='YOUR-IMAGE-URL' name='twitter:image'/>
  <meta content='YOUR-IMAGE-URL' name='twitter:image'/>
</if>
```

Or if you want to only apply in the homepage, maybe using the conditional `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'>`